# What is a "HEAP CORRUPTION" error in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm getting a "HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTRD: after Normal Block(#72)" error on a code.What does it mean?

I keep getting a "CRT detected the application wrote memory after end of heap buffer." error on a code in Visual Studio 2019 and it returns 3.But the same code when compiled with gcc gives no error and returns 0. After hours of searching I've found no solution.

```
#include <iostream>

    class Vector
    {
    public:
        Vector();
       ~Vector();
        std::size_t size() const { return m_end - m_begin; }
        std::size_t capacity() const { return m_capacity - m_begin; }
        int* begin() const { return m_begin; }
        int* end() const { return m_end; }
        void push_back(const int& );
        Vector(const Vector& obj)
    {
        int* rhs_beg = obj.m_begin;
        int* new_beg = alloc.allocate(size());
        int* temp_new_beg = new_beg;
        for (std::size_t it = 0; it != size(); ++it)
        {
            alloc.construct(temp_new_beg++, *rhs_beg++);
        }
        m_begin = new_beg;
        m_capacity = m_end = temp_new_beg;
    }


    private:
      std::allocator<int> alloc;
      int* m_begin, *m_end, *m_capacity;
          void chk_n_alloc();
      void allocate();
      void free();
};

    Vector::Vector()
    :m_begin(nullptr), m_end(nullptr), m_capacity(nullptr)
    {
    }

    void Vector::free()
    {
       for (auto it = m_end; it != m_begin;)
        alloc.destroy(--it);
       alloc.deallocate(m_begin, size());
    }

    void Vector::chk_n_alloc()
    { 
       if (size() == capacity())
        allocate();
    }

    void Vector::allocate()
    {
       std::size_t n_size;
       int* beg = nullptr;
       if (!size())
        beg = alloc.allocate(1);
       else
                beg = alloc.allocate(size() * 2);
       int* new_begin = beg;
       int* t_begin = m_begin;
       for (int i = 0; i != size(); ++i)
                alloc.construct(new_begin++, std::move(*t_begin++));
       free();
       m_begin = beg;
       m_end = new_begin;
       n_size = size() * 2;
       m_capacity = m_begin + n_size;
    }

      void Vector::push_back(const int& x)
    {
        chk_n_alloc();
        alloc.construct(m_end++, x);
    }

    Vector::~Vector()
    {
        free();
    }

    int main()
    {
       Vector v;

       v.push_back(12);
       v.push_back(10);

    }
```

The error takes place only if I try to call Vector::push_back() more than once.Here is the Error code : "HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTRD: after Normal Block(#72)."

Comment: Hi. It's not the direct reason why you're getting the heap issue, but you might want to rethink the use of pointers for `size()` and `capacity()`. You're effectively subtracting addresses of pointers, not integer values.

Comment: The valgrind result when compiling with clang++ 8.0.0: https://pastebin.com/wc7Dhw01 
When compiling with g++ 9.2.1 it found no errors.

Comment: with gcc and valgrind it points to an error on my pc... ==8330== Invalid write of size 4
==8330==    at 0x401696: void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::construct<int, int const&>(int*, int const&) (new_allocator.h:136)

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i != size();)` How is this loop supposed to end? It creates an infinite loop when you copy elements from the old memory to the new. Thus, you end up writing over memory that doesn't belong to you.

Comment: The loop has an increment in the source code.But I somehow maybe deleted it accidentally in the post.The same error occurs even with the increment.I'll edit the post to add that.

Answer (score 1):

It means your program is writing to memory it shouldn't and overwriting the administrative memory that the runtime uses to manage the heap.

Common causes are:

- Writing outside of an allocated block. E.g. `new[]` an array of size 4, and write to the 5th or 6th (etc.) item. Negative offsets could also could this.
- Freeing memory and writing to it afterwards.
- Dereferencing (and writing to) uninitialized pointers that point to random memory locations

In your code, I would carefully double check which memory you access, when you access it and whether it's safe to do so at that time. You can use a debugger to trace what your code is doing, or build/run with an address sanitizer, which gives more meaningful info about these kinds of errors.

Comment: ... and since it is *heap* corruption, the memory being overwritten is reserved with new, malloc or other heap-based allocation, so it isn't for instance a normal stack-bound array.